# PostgreSQL: How to modify the text before /copy it

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have some customer data like the following saved in a text file:

```
|Mr   |Peter   |Bradley   |72 Milton Rise   |Keynes    |MK41 2HQ   |
|Mr   |Kevin   |Carney    |43 Glen Way      |Lincoln   |LI2 7RD    | 786 3454
```

I copied the aforementioned data into my `customer` table using the following command:

```
\copy customer(title, fname, lname, addressline, town, zipcode, phone) from 'customer.txt' delimiter '|'
```

However, as it turns out, there are some extra space characters before and after various parts of the data. What I'd like to do is call `trim()` before copying the data into the table - what is the best way to achieve this?

Is there a way to call `trim()` on every value of every row and avoid inserting unclean data in the first place?

Thanks,

Comment: If the data is stored in a flat file, then it's easy enough to put together a simple script that would remove the spaces.

Comment: @JackManey Yes, it is in a flat file. Could you give some details about the simple script, please?

Comment: Why not import it to a temporary table, clean it up there, and then copy the clean data from the temp table to your final destination.

Comment: @muistooshort By saying clean it up, do you mean call trim() on every single column? That is the only way I can think of. Just wondering if there is a better way to handle this issue.

Comment: @DenLi In your position I'd write a small Python script that used the `csv` module to load the data, trim and otherwise clean it, then write each row with `psycopg2`, or just stream it to the stdin of a `psql` that's running `COPY ... FROM STDIN`. In fact, you can probably even do it with `awk` if your data is simple. Replace Python with your language of choice. Otherwise, yeah, you'll need to load it into a `TEMPORARY` table in the DB as-is then strip unwanted chars from each col as you `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` it into the real target table.

Comment: You might investigate using a foreign data wrapper to access the file, and modify the data as you select from it.

Comment: @DenLi - Just use a scripting language of your choice (eg Perl, Python, etc) that has a CSV parsing library. It's not that difficult, and should only take 5--10 minutes in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I have somehow similar use case in one of the projects. My input files:

- has number of lines in the file as a last line;
- needs to have line numbers added on every line;
- needs to have file_id added to every line.

I use the following piece of `shell` code:

```sh
FACT=$( dosql "TRUNCATE tab_raw RESTART IDENTITY;
COPY tab_raw(file_id,lnum,bnum,bname,a_day,a_month,a_year,a_time,etype,a_value)
 FROM stdin WITH (DELIMITER '|', ENCODING 'latin1', NULL '');
$(sed -e '$d' -e '=' "$FILE"|sed -e 'N;s/\n/|/' -e 's/^/'$DSID'|/')
\.
VACUUM ANALYZE tab_raw;
SELECT count(*) FROM tab_raw;
" | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//' -e '/^$/d'
)
```

`dosql` is a shell function, that executes `psql` with proper connectivity info and executes everything, that was given as an argument.

As a result of this operation I will have `$FACT` variable holding a total count of inserter records (for error detection).

Later I do another `dosql` call:

```
dosql "SET work_mem TO '800MB';
SELECT tab_prepare($DSID);
VACUUM ANALYZE tab_raw;
SELECT tab_duplicates($DSID);
SELECT tab_dst($DSID);
SELECT tab_gaps($DSID);
SELECT tab($DSID);"
```

to get analyze and move data into the final tables from auxiliary one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go about this is to add a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to the table you're inserting to.  This way, you can write a stored procedure that will execute before every record is inserted and trim whitepsace (or do any other transformations you may need) on any columns that need it.  When you're done, simply remove the trigger (or leave it, which will improve data integrity if you never want that whitespace int those columns).  I think explaining how to create a trigger and stored procedure in PostgreSQL is probably outside the scope of this question, but I will link to the documentation for each.

I think this is the best way because it is simpler than parsing through a text file or writing shell code to do this.  This kind of sanitization is the kind of thing triggers do very well and very simply.

[Creating a Trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

[Creating a Trigger Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)